# How do install a specific version of Bower with NPM

Tags: npm, version, bower

I would like to install version 1.3.9 of bower with NPM.
I have tried the following:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g bower
```

(successful)

```
sudo npm install -g bower#1.3.9
```

Even though bower re-installs correctly the version remains at the latest version, 1.3.12, not at the desired 1.3.9

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use the @ sign instead of #:

```
npm install -g bower@1.3.9
```

For more details see [npm-install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install)